# Find the dimension of the real Lie algebra su(n)={A∈sln(C)|A+A∗ =0}, A∗ =A(conjugate transpose)

Tags: lie-algebras, vector-space-isomorphism

Find the dimension of the real Lie algebra
 su(n)={A∈sln(C)|A+A∗ =0}, A∗ =At.
Also have to Show that the map
A∗ =At. C⊗R su(n)→sln(C), z⊗A→zA
su(n)={A∈sln(C)|A+A∗ =0},
￼is an isomorphism (of complex vector spaces or complex Lie algebras). The algebra
C ⊗R su(n) is called the complexification of the real Lie algebra su(n).

I know that the inverse map is A → 1 ⊗(A−A∗)− i ⊗i(A+A∗). How do I verify this and compare dimensions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By the definition you gave, $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ consists of skew-Hermitian matrices. This vector space has real dimension $n^2-1$, so that we have 
$$
\dim \mathfrak{su}(n)=n^2-1.
$$